# How to create mixins in saas for keyframes using transform

Tags: html, css, sass, mixins

I am working in sass files. i have a problem related mixins. i creating a mix-ins for key frames and i have no idea how to create. i have added my code below. please review my code and please create a mix-ins for this. if i copy this code in directly in complied css file then css file automatically remove these key frames.I am working in sass files. i have a problem related mixins. i creating a mix-ins for key frames and i have no idea how to create. i have added my code below. please review my code and please create a mix-ins for this. if i copy this code in directly in complied css file then css file automatically remove these key frames.

```
.heart-beat {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    z-index: 10;
    border: 5px solid #ef5350;
    border-radius: 70px;
    -moz-animation: heartbit 1s ease-out;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation: heartbit 1s ease-out;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation: heartbit 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
}


@-moz-keyframes heartbit {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0.0; }
    25% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
        opacity: 0.1; }
    50% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
        opacity: 0.3; }
    75% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
        opacity: 0.5; }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 0.0; } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes heartbit {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0.0; }
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
        opacity: 0.1; }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        opacity: 0.3; }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
        opacity: 0.5; }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 0.0; } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the example of the `mixin`.This may help you.
Where `keyframe()` is used to call the keyframe prefix, then `prefixed()` is used for transform property.

To see the compile code please use [SASS Meister online tool](https://www.sassmeister.com/)

```
   // This is for iterating `Keyframes`    
        @include keyframes(heartbit){

    // This is for iterating `transform`
        @include prefixed(transform, scale(0.1);

        }
```

Note: You need to declare this below the mixin.

---

```
// Mixin

// prefix declarations
    @mixin prefixed($property, $value) {

        -webkit-#{$property}: #{$value};
        -moz-#{$property}: #{$value};
        -ms-#{$property}: #{$value};
        -o-#{$property}: #{$value};
        #{$property}: #{$value};

    }

    // prefix keyframes
    @mixin keyframes($name) {

        @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
          @content;
         }

        @-moz-keyframes #{$name} {
          @content;
        }

        @-ms-keyframes #{$name} {
          @content;
        }

        @-o-keyframes #{$name} {
          @content;
        }

        @keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I am very confused, please can you please create a mixin for me. so i can use asit is in mu scss file.

Comment: Here I have attached the SCSS for the above requirement, check out my codepen. https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/YrvLNQ

Comment: If my solution works fine, please mark it as correct. Thanks :)